# How to break current iteration and continue with next iteration within setInterval()?

Tags: javascript, timing

Just like `continue` is used to break current iteration and proceed with the next, how can I break current iteration within `setInterval()` in JavaScript and proceed with the next interval without waiting?

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval( function() {
   if(conditionIsTrue) {
      // Break this iteration and proceed with the next
      // without waiting for 3 seconds.
   }
}, 3000 );
```

Comment: where is your iteration. Is there any loop?

Comment: Can you give us a little better idea of what you're trying to do. At the moment it sounds like you're trying to blow up your web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could "simply" (or not so simply) clear the interval, and re-create it:

```
// run the interval function immediately, then start the interval
var restartInterval = function() {
    intervalFunction();
    intervalID = setInterval(intervalFunction, 3000 );
};

// the function to run each interval
var intervalFunction = function() {
    if(conditionIsTrue) {
      // Break this iteration and proceed with the next
      // without waiting for 3 seconds.

      clearInterval(intervalID);
      restartInterval();
   }
};

// kick-off
var intervalID = window.setInterval(intervalFunction, 3000 );
```

[Here's a demo/test Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6J4vv/)

Comment: Yeah I think the breaking the `invervalFunction` out into its own function makes the whole thing make way more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Just tested this, and it acts as a continue statement in a loop. For fellow coders finding this now, just use `return` within the setInterval.

```
var myRepeater = setInterval( function() {
   if(conditionIsTrue) {
      return;
   }
}, 1000 );
```

EDIT: To comply with the immediate execution after breaking the current execution of the loop, one could instead do something like so (in theory. And beware of recursion issues if `conditionIsTrue` stays **true**):

```
function myFunction() {
    if(conditionIsTrue) {
       myFunction();
       return;
    }
    // Interval function code here...
}

var myRepeater = setInterval( myFunction, 1000 );
```

Comment: this won't start the next iteration immediately though

Comment: @AniketSuryavanshi You're right, I missed that. I added an additional solution for that.